# How to mock hibernate getSessionFactory?

Tags: mockito

How to mock

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
```

using mockito?

Comment: What @wjans said. Also you could have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mock a static method with Mockito.  Have a look at [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) ([PowerMockito](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13)).  But note that it also has some drawbacks, like for instance performance.